# Force DHCP client to use only IPv4

Tags: dhcp, ipv4, systemd-networkd

I have Linux client (running systemd-networkd, version 244), and I want to configure it's network only with IPv4. However, the DHCP server offers both v4 and v6. Is it possible to limit the client to only take the IPv4 configuration?

I configured the DHCP client to ipv4. The network configuration file looks like this:

```
~# cat /etc/systemd/network/80-wlp10s0.network 

[DHCPv4]
UseRoutes=false

[Link]
MTUBytes=1500
Unmanaged=no

[Match]
Name=wlp10s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
IPForward=no

[Route]
Destination=192.168.1.0/24
Gateway=192.168.2.34
GatewayOnLink=yes
```

And yet, I get both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses configured:

```
~# ifconfig wlp10s0   
wlp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
        inet 192.168.2.136  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::6f0:21ff:fe5a:ee8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:f0:21:5a:0e:e8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33043  bytes 22019800 (20.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2913  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20144  bytes 11873580 (11.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

PS. I do want to disable IPv6 entirely. A different network interface can be configured to use IPv6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable ipv6 support in Linux entirely?](https://serverfault.com/questions/660979/how-to-disable-ipv6-support-in-linux-entirely)

Comment: No.  A different network interface can be configured to use IPv6, therefore removing IPv6 entirely is not a good solution. This would be a very radical fix for a configuration option.